# ways to figure out compression algorithm used on string using python

Tags: python, encoding, base64, compression

I have a base64 encoded string (assumption) that when decoded, appears to be compressed binary data (assumption).

I'd like to use python to "force" decompress the data with as many decompression algorithms as possible, to figure out it's plain text.

This is what I tried so far, without success. Any ideas?

```
import base64
import gzip
from StringIO import StringIO

magic_dict = {
    "\x1f\x8b\x08": "gz",
    "\x42\x5a\x68": "bz2",
    "\x50\x4b\x03\x04": "zip"
    }

string ="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"

string = base64.b64decode(string)

#try to determine compression
for magic, filetype in magic_dict.items():
    if string.startswith(magic):
        print filetype

#try to simply gunzip the string, no sucess         
print gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=StringIO(string)).read()
```

Comment: The most obvious question - are you sure one of the 3 compression algorithms is the one used? Did your program print any filetype? (sorry for not commenting - but I don't have enough points yet)

Comment: nope it did not match on any of these and I did not extend the programm due to a lack of magic bytes for other algorithms. I wonder, if there is a another way of doing it?

Comment: On Unix machines, you have the `file` command which is dedicated to the task of determining a file type relying on its magic number. It relies on a magic number database available in a directory like `/usr/share/misc/magic`, the source version of this database (provided along the compiled binary version with most distros) may be of some help to you. You can find more information on [the Wikipedia page about the file command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_%28command%29), and in particular the last "*Other*" section linking to libmagic sources and an alternative software.

Comment: @Vilican & John ingmar: BTW I've created a new discussion on Meta to discuss [if and how flags for comments posted as answers could be improved](http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/q/2123/32746).

Comment: If this is not a compressed file format, but only the compressed data, the `file` command won't help. You will probably have to try "all" of them. Btw, if this is about compression algorithms, why are there the tags: [encryption], [cryptography] and [pycrypto]? Where is the [compression] tag?